# Create hive table via csv file contains columns type in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a project that consist to create a generic script shell to create several hive tables in function of columns type and data, so :
1- I want to read a csv file which contains columns type and store the output in a variable. 
2- Write a HIVE query to create table via this variable.

This is for example my csv file :

```
id string,num_article string,dt_depot string
```

-The script idea is :

```
#!/bin/bash
#readcolumns.sh


while read line; do
     echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2,$3}'

done < $cat columns.csv
```

At the end, My query HQL will be like:

```
#!/bin/bash
hive --database -e "create table $nametable $columns"
```

Comment: Kindly consider adding a little one or two line example of the data for more clarity

Comment: What should the queries be matching presented input? [How to read a file field by field in bashfaq](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) The presented loop is just `awk -F ',' '{print $1,$2,$3}' columns.csv`, dunno. What should the script idea represent?